# Usando LOG em Funções de VISUALG

Tags: algoritmo, visualg, portugol

Ao usar LOG em visualG esta ocorrendo um problema, eu preciso dividir um valor digitado pelo usuário, por log 2 na base 10. Só que ele não faz isso ele da erro.

```
funcao menu_8():inteiro
var
logaritmo :real
inicio
para contador de 0 ate 12 faca
      logaritmo <- ((log(i[contador])) / (log(2)))
      se ((logaritmo % 2 = 0) OU (logaritmo % 2 = 1)) entao
         escreva(" é Potencia de 2: ", i[contador])
      fimse
fimpara
escreval(" ")
fimfuncao
```

apos a função SE ser executada e o resultado da divisão for um valor INTEIRO, sem virgula, ele imprime a mensagem, caso contrario, ele faz o laço de repetição com outro valor do vetor, ate encontrar um numero que seja potencia de 2, se nenhum for, ai ele vai fora e não imprime nada.

qual o caminho mais fácil para resolver isso?

Answer (score 1):

O problema está na comparação, exatamente no SE, você deve verificar se o resultado é inteiro de outra forma, se não tiver uma função relativa a "módulo" (**MOD**) que costuma capturar somente a parte fracionária de um número Real, não são todas as linguagens que têm, se não tiver, faça com a função que pega a parte inteira, assim:

Se **INT(Resultado) - Resultado = 0** , então a operação não apresenta resto, ou seja, é um número inteiro.

Por exemplo:

```
Se   INT(123) - 123 = 0  'Então  123  É um número inteiro

Se   INT(45,678) - 45,678 = 0,678  'Então  45,678 NÃO É um número inteiro
```

Comment: Oi @AGenaro, viu minha resposta?